# Fetching data from api and render it takes too much time

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js, fetch, fetching-strategy

**navigation menu**

```
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import Link from "next/link";
import { getAllCategories } from "src/utils/api";

export default async function NavMenu() {
  const {data: categories} = await getAllCategories();

  return (
    <div className="NavMenu">
      <ul className="NavMenu__categories">
        {categories?.map((cat) => (
          <li key={uuid()} className="NavMenu__category">
            <Link href={`/category/${cat.name}`} prefetch={true}>{cat.name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**category page: (opens when click on link from above)**

```
export default async function CategoryPage({ params }) {
  
  const { data: products } = await getProductsByCategory(params.id);

  return (
    <div className="CategoryPage">
      <div className="CategoryPage__grid">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <ProductCard key={uuid()} name={product.name} price={product.price} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="CategoryPage__pagination">
        <Pagination />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***fetching data from api function:***

```
export async function getProductsByCategory(category) {
  const url = productsURL;
  const params = {
    category_slug: category,
  };
  Object.keys(params).forEach((key) =>
    url.searchParams.append(key, params[key])
  );

  const products = await fetchTemplate(productsURL, "GET", publicHeaders);
  return products;
}
```

Too much time for loading items from api.

I have 15 items in api. When fetching data for a specific category page, it filters 3 items, but it takes something around 4-6 seconds to render.

When I click on link, it navigates to category page.

But it takes too much time.

I guess in such cases, I have to choose a better approach to fetching data from api.

Do you have some suggestions for improvements?

Comment: When you debug, what is the actual bottleneck?  If the API takes 4-6 seconds to respond then the code shown wouldn't have any control over that.

Comment: The problem is the time it takes to render, and this with only 15 items in db. Then when I click logo to navigate home, it also takes too much time.

Comment: Did you measure that it's rendering time, or is it fetch time? Look at your browser's network inspector. If the API is being slow, you need to fix that, not the frontend.

Comment: Content Download 9.7s . So the reason is it takes to much time to download the content.

Comment: @VasileMidrigan: *"The problem is the time it takes to render [...] the reason is it takes to much time to download"* - Those are two very different things.  Again, if the server takes a long time to respond then that has exactly nothing to do with the client-side rendering of the data.  It's important that you identify the actual bottleneck rather than make random changes to the code based on guesses or assumptions.  What you're showing in the question above is client-side code, but the problem you're now describing is server-side.

Comment: The fact is that Content Download indicator in dev tool shows 9sec, which means is a network problem, so I guess I have to implement loading UI. But again, why it takes so much time? If I will run the function and console.log the result, I will see the results instantly. Can't understand why is that happening.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The problem was that for some reason, fetching data by using `category_slug` as a params works pretty slow, something ~7s, but changing params to `category_id` solves the problem. Now it fetches data with ~1.3s . So it should be problem from API.